# Where does Alfred store web searches?

Tags: mac, preferences, alfred

Where does [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) store default and custom web searches that you create on your Mac?

Answer (score 2):

*(Note, 1) I have my Alfred preferences located on my dropbox, but the default location is at ~/Library/Application Support/Alfred 2, i.e., in your home folder's Library folder, and 2) the following is for the Alfred 2 app)*

Using **sudo opensnoop | grep Alfred.alfredpreferences** in terminal (if using this you'll need to provide your admin password), I see that adding a custom web search updates the following file within the Alfred.alfredpreferences.

*Alfred.alfredpreferences/preferences/features/websearch/prefs.plist* in the Finder.

You'll need to **right-click** on the **Alfred.alfredpreferences** file to "**Show Package Contents**" to view these folders.

Once you've navigated to the .plist file, it can be view via **Quicklook** by pressing the **Space Bar** whist the file is highlighted.

Comment: Thanks. I see the **custom searches** that I have created in the `prefs.plist` file but where are the **default searches** that come with Alfred when you install it stored

Comment: It looks like a change to a default search updates: Alfred.alfredpreferences/preferences/local/. There is a unique folder that then has several files update, including: /appearance, /appearance/options, /features, /features/clipboard, /features/defaultresults, /features/defaultresults/scope, /features/filenavigation, /features/filenavigation/customhomefolder, /hotkey, and /update. That's all I can help you with. You may have some success in contacting [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/support/) directly.